# Amazon S3 and resource protection

Tags: mobile, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am building a mobile application with a server-side backend.
Application has a lot of different functionality + some social network functionality.

The problem I am experiencing is about protecting resources on Amazon S3.

Let's imagine, that user has received an url to Amazon S3, where his friend's picture is stored. The url is something like:

```
    https://bucket-name.amazon.com/some-unique-id-of-the-picture
```

So now the user can randomly ( or sequentially ) start generating some-unique-id-of-the-picture and get the access to other user's private pictures. How can I restrict this?

Actually, I am more-less OK to that ( these pictures aren't very confidential in our application ), however, some of the user's really confidential data is stored on Amazon S3 as well ( in another bucket ). And I definitely need to secure them.

How can I secure this data?

Using time-limited URLs is not an option. 
Here is why:
1) Downloading the resource by time-limited URL and then just use the local copy - slows down the application ( reading BLOB data from SQLite on Android is slow ) and the application takes a lot of storage
2) Caching of the resources and storing just URLs won't work. Since user can empty the cache, but URL will already expire.

At the moment the only solution I see:
Make all the requests via our server, check if the user can see requested resource, then read the data from amazon and return it to the user.
Unfortunately, this would produce quite significant load on our server(s).

Any help/advice or suggestions would be highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've seen this being used by sites : Really long Unique Ids for images that are hard to guess and regenerate. For example, if your image name is UUID1_UUID2_UUID3.jpg, it becomes nearly impossible to guess the image names via a sequential attack. [UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) . Just check the images from Facebook. Will think more about protecting it completely without too much load on the server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We also thought about this method, but for pictures, which aren't very confidential. However, for other sensitive stuff we want something more secured.

Do you think, that Amazon S3 will block somebody if he starts guessing the urls?

Comment: I don't think so (unless they detect it as a DoS attack). For sensitive stuff - how frequently will the image files be accessed? If it isn't too much load, I guess it would be okay to serve it via the application.